# Add a subscriber to a list using Marketing Cloud SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I'm trying to add a subscriber to a list by a SOAP call to the MC API, using this example:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/adding_subscribers_to_a_list.htm

The xml response return 200 OK and says that the subscriber was added to the list, but if I open the list then the subscriber doesn't shows. Also, if I execute the same call again then server responses with a 200 OK and says that the subscriber was already added.

I don't know if first I have to create the subscriber or that call create the subscriber and also add it to the list.

I was wondering if on the SOAP envelope I have to specify the id of the list or the external key.

Thanks!
Alvaro

Answer (score 0):

Well what I finally do is to create a Data Extension using the MC user interface, then I create a User Initiated Email also using the UI.
Then using Apex, I made a SOAP call to add subscribers to the Data Extension and then a I made another SOAP call to fire the User Initiated Send so mass email was sended to all the subscribers.

If anyone needs to see the xml envelope of both actions I can show here.

Regards